# Change values in row based on a column value and replacing specified column range

Tags: r, excel, replace, dataframe

I found most of my answer with : [Change values in row based on a column value r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222632/change-values-in-row-based-on-a-column-value-r) . There are two differences: I want to replace values based on test of a categorical variable and I want to specify the range for which I want the values to be replaced. I am working with a data frame of 8600 odd rows and 170 columns.

Here's an example:-

```
x = data.frame(c("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April"), 
               c(9,3,4,6), c(8, 12,9,11), c(10, 9, 7, 0.6))
names(x) = c("Month","VAR1","VAR2", "VAR3")
```

I want to replace all the values of VAR2 and VAR3 (not VAR1) where month is "March" or "April" with  `NA`.

I tried: `x[x$Month==c("March", "April"), ] <- data.frame('x', NA, 3:4)` but I get the error

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(1L, 1L)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

and `print(x)` gives:

```
  Month VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
1   Jan    9    8   10
2   Feb    3   12    9
3  <NA>   NA    3    1
4  <NA>   NA    4    1
```

There is some obvious programming beginner syntactical error I am unable to get past!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
x[x$Month %in% c("March", "April"), c("VAR2", "VAR3")] = NA
```

Comment: Hopefully that becomes self-explanatory after examining it, but I'll be glad to expand if that would help.

Comment: is self explanatory ! Just one hitch: here you are able to  specify `c("VAR2" , "VAR3")` . In my original DF, I have VAR1 to VAR 164. It's painful to type that many names !

Comment: I'll start with a hint but will be glad to expand if it's not enough. Take a look at `paste` (or `sprintf`) and `rep` to see if you can replicate what you need without typing that much :-)

Comment: very cool. btw: that is one of the best SO R questions I've seen. Rly great job both in researching your problem and showing a reproducible example.

Comment: used `sprintf` like so `x[x$Month %in% c("March", "April"), c(sprintf("VAR%.i", 3:6))] = NA`